# How do functions operates in a Fourier algebra $A^{q}(\mathbb T)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

We put , $A^{q}(\mathbb T)= \{ f\in L^{q}(\mathbb T): \hat{f}\in \ell^{q}(\mathbb Z) \}.$
By [Helson-Kahane-Katznelson-Rudin Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_algebra), it follows that,

"Let $F$ be a function on $\mathbb C$ and if $F(f)\in A^{1}(\mathbb T)$ whenever $f\in A^{1}(\mathbb T)$($F(f)$ is the composition of $F$ and f)(i.e, $F$ operates in $A^{1}(\mathbb T)$), then $F$ must be real-analytic on $\mathbb R^{2}.$"

> **My Question is**: If $F$ operates in  $A^{q}(\mathbb T), (1< q \leq \infty) $. Then what can we say about $F$ ? If it is well-known, and not trivial, references would be o.k. for me.

[We note, $q=2$, it is just $L^{2}(\mathbb T)$ we may not expect the exact analogue]